How to align icons with css
I want this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
There is a list of icons arranged in an array.
I want the spacing of each icon to be the same, but I want to attach both ends of each row to the side. How should I write the code?
I want to attach both ends to each side with the spacing equally spaced.
I tried it.
display: flex;
flex-direction: rows;
item-aligns: center;
justify-content: space-between;

but result is:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
and i tried is:
justfy-contents: start or flex-start;

result is:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

"I want to attach both ends to each side with the spacing equally spaced." That's what justify-content: space-between seems to have given you. Please be more specific with how you want the layout to look, perhaps by providing an image showing what you want. You can also experiment with different layouts on https://flexbox.tech/

You can use this hack

display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; flex-flow: row wrap; flex-direction: rows; item-aligns: center; margin-left: inherit;

@smallbee I love you! thank you!
